# Deploy a Vue.js app to Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, vue.js

We have a node.js application that we built its front-end with VueJS, we deployed our back-end code (java spring) properly and we got a link (https://ourWebAppexample.net)  that runs the back-end code as expected.
We usually run the front-end on a local host from a folder that contains the code with "npm run dev". 
Now we want to deploy the front-end to Azure web-app using Visual Studio Azure extension.
We tried some tutorials (like: https://code.visualstudio.com/tutorials/app-service-extension/getting-started) and we got deployment successful  but it didn't work properly.
How do we deploy a Vue.js application to Azure and get a "link" where our front-end code should run? is there any other way to deploy a node.js code (not using Visual Studio) ?

Comment: You can deploy a node js app from azure CLI, git CLI and of course Visual studio.

Comment: `we got deployment successful but it didn't work properly.` Is there any exception?   Could you add more information about `It didn't work`? If there is a screenshot about `It didn't work` will be better.

Comment: @TomSun there were problems with the https and http, we fixed it by adding a web.confing file and now it works fine, thank you